# How do I set up a material with diffuse, normal and alpha (transparency) maps?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor, transparency

I'm finding it very difficult to set up a basic material with diffuse, alpha and normal maps. Although I've managed to create a material with diffuse and normal maps, I can't manage to get the alpha channel working correctly. I would like to use three *separate* maps as shown below:

[image: DIFFUSE]

[image: NORMAL]

[image: ALPHA]

Below is the desired result of combining the maps with a single spotlight shining from above.

[image: DESIRED RESULT]

Although I found a few examples of setting up materials with transparency online, I couldn't get anything to work correctly. Instead of me posting lots of pictures of my failed setup, **could someone explain the correct way to combine these maps? I would really like to see both how to do it in the standard material/texture panels, and also in the node editor. I would like the result to appear in the real-time textured viewport mode.**

In order to help explain what I am trying to set up, here is a picture of the current result of the material as it looks with lighting in my scene. I'm viewing using GLSL, but if I switch to multitexture, it's entirely black. I tried rendering it, but I just get the result shown here.

[image: CURRENT RESULT]

**UPDATE: Partial Answer**

Thanks to **[this](http://www.blendernerd.com/alpha-mapping-in-cycles/)** tutorial, I managed to achieve the result I want if I'm rendering in cycles. The problem with this is that I want a clean real-time render that works in the viewport, so I'm still only half-way to a real answer. Here's my node setup for cycles:

[image: Cycles node setup]

However, as I said, I would like to see this kind of bump mapping working with alpha in the standard real-time view:

[image]

Comment: blender internal or cycles?

Comment: Multitexture illuminates per-vertex, so it will be entirely black where there are no vertices to illuminate (as is the case on a single quad).

Comment: David: I'm really looking for an answer that will allow me to see it working in real-time in the viewport, since rendering is not the goal. Is the setup different for the different renderers too?

Comment: I just updated the question with information about doing it in cycles. However, a weird thing I noticed in cycles is that the light does not appear to be hitting the object at the right angle; The illuminated area is off to one side, rather than perfectly centered, and I've no idea why this is.

Answer (score 3):

The only problem I see in the node setup is that the normal map image texture should be put through a *normal map* node to convert the *color* output data of the image texture to the required *normal* input of the shader.

Answer (score -2):

If you are working in Cycles, it isn't currently possible to view the alpha channel in the textured view. The rendered view is the only current workaround.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what about if I'm not using cycles? The game engine presumably supports rendering alpha cutout textures with normal maps, so I guess there is a way to set it up somehow.

Comment: Material view supports transparency.

Comment: @MrFlamey Are you using Blender internal render, Blender game render or cycles? Your question didn't make it clear.